# What is the sum of all pairwise products of a number's digits called?

Tags: terminology

I'm looking for something like this and I want to know how it's called; I'm pretty sure there is a term for it.

I will show an example: Let's say we take the number 9876. 
$$x=9\cdot8+9\cdot7+9\cdot6+8\cdot7+8\cdot6+7\cdot6$$
You can see I multiply each pair of digits and then add.

Comment: I don't have a name for it, but you might be interested that $x=\frac{(9+8+7+6)^2-(9^2+8^2+7^2+6^2)}{2}$, which reduces the number of computations when there are lots of digits.

Comment: I would be very surprised if such a thing had a name!

Comment: @RossMillikan yeah I just got it from there just didn't multiply by 2 and thought it would be nice to remember, but it would be easier to remember if I know name of it, but maybe it doesn't exist :/

Answer (score 2):

Not specific to sums of digits, but [symmetric polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_polynomial) are up this alley.  Does this help?